# Having trouble making container responsive to vertical shrinking

Tags: css, responsive-design

I've created a fiddle that replicates what's going on here. Basically, I have outer/inner modal divs, and a container inside the inner modal.

When the content inside the container is too much to display inside the inner modal, I want the top part to display and a scroll bar to appear. When the content inside the container is small enough to be displayed in its entirety, I want it vertically centered.

However, what actually happens is: if the content is larger than the inner modal, the top part is cut off. A scroll bar appears, but I can only scroll down; there is no way to access the content at the top.

I think I must have gone wrong somewhere in my CSS. I'd really appreciate any help!

http://jsfiddle.net/d16xc8vm/

```
CSS:
.page {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

.modal-background {
    position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 1.875rem 1rem;
  z-index: 10;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal-child {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  overflow: scroll;
  transition: all ease 1s;
}

.foo-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

i.fa-times {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: -5px;
  right: 0;
}

.foo-header {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab-one, .tab-two {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: violet;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #009DAE;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}

.foo-index {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```
HTML:
<div class="page">
  blah blah
  
  <div class="modal-background">
    <div class="modal-child">
      <div class="foo-container">
        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        <div class="foo-header">
          <div class="tab-one">
            <span>Tab One</span>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-two">
            <span>Tab Two</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="foo-index">
          <ul>
            <li>Sample Text</li>
            <-- if the # of <li>s is too great, .foo-header starts getting cut off -->
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  please Add {float:left;} to **foo-index,foo-header** and  {display:block;} to foo-container 


.page {
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: white;
    }
    
    .modal-background {
        position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      padding: 1.875rem 1rem;
      z-index: 10;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .modal-child {
      position: relative;
      background: #FFF;
      width: 80vw;
      height: 80vh;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding-left: 1rem;
      padding-right: 1rem;
      padding-top: 1rem;
      padding-bottom: 1rem;
      overflow: scroll;
      transition: all ease 1s;
    }
    
    .foo-container {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    i.fa-times {
      position: absolute;
      font-size: 20px;
      top: -5px;
      right: 0;
    }
    
    .foo-header {
      width: 100%;
      display: grid;
      float:left;
      margin-top: 1.5rem;
      align-items: center;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr;
      grid-gap: 5px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .tab-one, .tab-two {
      margin: 0 0 20px;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: violet;
      border-radius: 8px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #009DAE;
      font-weight: 700;
      transition: 0.3s ease-out;
    }
    
    .foo-index {
      float:left;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      display: grid;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 1.5rem;
      grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-gap: 10px;
     padding: 0;
}
```

[image: see the screenshot here]

Comment: please Add {float:left;} to **foo-index,foo-header** and  {display:block;} to foo-container

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask why this fixes it? I thought {display:flex} was supposed to push the content into view too

Comment: The display property is used to set one of two values: flex & inline-flex.

If you set display to flex, all children inside of the container become a flex item. They will be automatically arranged into a row and each element will be the same width as their content. The flex container spans its own width, and each child has to fit in the container's width.
If you set display to inline-flex, it makes the flex container behave like an inline element.